# BigQuery: Selecting the week from Google Analytics data using standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm working with Google Analytics data in a Google Big Query table using standard sql. I wish to select group data at a weekly level. I've found this solution:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%W", PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", '20150519'))
```

Outputs:

```
20
```

Is there a shorter method to get to this point? It seem quite long to me and I'm wondering if I'm missing a trick.

Comment: For what i could see here you are right, the `EXTRACT` functions in standard BQ does not support the `WEEK` option https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract. Looks like you'll have to stick to your solution (maybe issuing a feature request to them to support this might be interesting)

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=743.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "improvement" I see can be done - is using `PARSE_DATE` instead of `PARSE_TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%W", PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", '20150519'))
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that's tidier. Good to know I'm not a million miles out.